# How to model motorcycle clutch and gearbox?

Tags: modeling

I need to model this motorcycle part:
[image]

Motorcycle - [reference motorcycle](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/harley-davidson-motorcycle-576a0ff6ac354522bd617326f083474b)

I create two components:
[image: the result is]
And connected them:
[image: result]
but the result is bad.

How would you make such model?

Answer (score 0):

Draw the lines of the shape:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Pull some faces:

[image]

Comment: But how you draw lines? Just by hand or maybe some smart tool?

Comment: I mean - how did you understand that the lines should bend this way? Maybe this is some technique?

Comment: What I did is not faithful to what you show, it's just show a way to begin. To draw the lines, create some circles, extrude its vertices, etc